# Trying to beautify a line of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing variable substitution in a jquery expression. It just looks kind of ugly. Wondering if someone knew a better way to do this?

... looping through a calendar, looking at dates to high-light in a calendar table, code excerpt:

```
var = 31;
$('#s' + var + '').css({"background-color":"blue","color":"white"});
```

This does work, just the syntax is a bit un-elegant.  Thanks.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hgssreh6/2/ .. copy your code into jsfiddle and click on the link `Tidy` on top.. gives the best readable code. There are other js beautifiers too but this is what I use.

Comment: To simplify your code, you'd have to provide us a larger view of your code such as the whole function carrying out this operation so we could offer better ways of doing things.  Just rewriting one line of code is not open to very many optimizations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need the `$('#s' + var + '')`.  This should be enough:

```
var xyz = 31;
$('#s' + xyz).css({"background-color":"blue","color":"white"});
```

I am sure this is just an example, but don't name a var `var`.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick response. Yes, var just slipped in.  That's a crazy name. It's really dayMonth.

Answer (score 1):

May You can create a class like

```
.highlight{
background:blue;
color:white;
}
```

And can simply add or remove as you wish

```
abc = 31;
$('#s' + abc).addClass("highlight");
```

if you want to remove the style , Just  use

```
 $('#s' + abc).removeClass("highlight");
```

Comment: Yes, much cleaner.

Comment: for highlighting ,its a good practice to encap the style in a new class . .

Answer (score 0):

If beautification it is that you want, my code structure is below.

```
    var xyz = 31;
    $('#s' + xyz).css({
        "background-color":"blue",
        "color":"white"
    });
```

I will do it like in my css file, because for me,
a readable code is a beautiful code.